# Receiving Multiple Order Emails Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, order-email

Occasionally **multiple order emails** are received by our order notification email from a single order. I cannot see any similar issues online currently for **Magento 2** just for Magento 1 and was wondering if anyone has experienced this and knows how to fix?

This is **intermittent** and has so far varied from 1 - 4 emails being sent to notify us that an order has been received. Am unsure if the customer is having the same issues at the moment.

This is currently on magento 2.1.7, with a few modules mainly Ebizmarts SagePay module.

### Update

Just want to update that i have continued through various updates since and problem has persisted up to 2.2.1 and will try 2.2.3 soon however do not think it will fix.

Issues here with other users on an Ebizmarts module so may be similar problem with their Sage Pay module:

https://github.com/ebizmarts/magento2-mandrill/issues/39